# export file with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

This project is an ASP.Net Api project with Angular. What I'm trying to do is export data from a database table and into an excel file. `So far, I've managed to export all the table data into an excel file, but struggle to select 2 or 3 fields in the table to export.`

```
        [HttpGet("download")]
        public IActionResult DownloadExcel(string field)
        {
            string dbFileName = "DbTableName.xlsx";


            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(dbFileName);
            byte[] fileContents;

            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(file))
            {

                IList<UserTable> userList = _context.UserTable.ToList();

                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("DbTableName");
                int totalUserRows = userList.Count();


            }


            return File(fileContents, fileType, dbFileName);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to write so many `if ... else if ... else if ... else if ...` to get the related field names.

A nicer way is to

1. Use a field list (`IList<string>`)as a parameter.
2. And then generate a required field list by `intersect`.
3. Finally, we could use reflection to retrieve all the related values.

**Implementation**

```
    public IActionResult DownloadExcel(IList<string> fields)
    {
        // get the required field list
        var userType = typeof(UserTable);
        fields = userType.GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).Intersect(fields).ToList();

        if(fields.Count == 0){ return BadRequest(); }

        using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            IList<UserTable> userList = _context.UserTable.ToList();
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("DbTableName");

            // generate header line
            for(var i= 0; i< fields.Count; i++ ){
                var fieldName = fields[i];
                var pi= userType.GetProperty(fieldName);
                var displayName =  pi.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>()?.DisplayName;
                worksheet.Cells[1,i+1].Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayName ) ? fieldName : displayName ;
            }

            // generate row lines
            int totalUserRows = userList.Count();
            for(var r=0; r< userList.Count(); r++){
                var row = userList[r];
                for(var c=0 ; c< fields.Count;c++){
                    var fieldName = fields[c];
                    var pi = userType.GetProperty(fieldName);
                    // because the first row is header 
                    worksheet.Cells[r+2, c+1].Value = pi.GetValue(row);
                }
            }
            var stream = new MemoryStream(package.GetAsByteArray());
            return new FileStreamResult(stream,"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        }
    }
```

You could configure the display name using the **`DsiplayNameAttribute`**:

```
    public class UserTable
    {
        public int Id{get;set;}

        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        public string fName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        public string lName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Gender")]
        public string gender { get; set; }

    }
```

It's possible to add any properties as you like without hard-coding in your `DownloadExcel` method.

**Demo** :

passing a field list `fields[0]=fName&fields[1]=lName&fields[2]=Non-Exist` will generate an excel as below:

[image]

**[Update]**

To export all the fields, we could assume the client will not pass a `fields` parameter. That means when the fields is `null` or if the `fields.Count==0`, we'll export all the fields:

```
    [HttpGet("download")]
    public IActionResult DownloadExcel(IList<string> fields)
    {
        // get the required field list
        var userType = typeof(UserTable);
        var pis= userType.GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name);

        if(fields?.Count >0){
            fields = pis.Intersect(fields).ToList();
        } else{
            fields = pis.ToList();
        }

        using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage()){
           ....
        }
    }
```

[image: A]

Comment: Oh my God @itminus! It worked so well!. Thank you so much for the assistance.

Comment: If I were wanting to export all the data from the table, can't I do something like fields=null? or fields=all?

Comment: @JennyFromtheBlock I've updated my answer. If the client doesn't specify a parameter  of `fields` ( that means `fields==null` or `fields.Count==0`), we will export all the fields.

Comment: I can't thank you enough! I have learned a lot! I hope this helps others as well!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the datatable then we can define which you need to select from the datatable in this way

```
string[] selectedColumns = new[] { "Column1","Column2"};
DataTable dt= new DataView(fromDataTable).ToTable(false, selectedColumns);
```

or else if you wanna you list then you can use linq for selection of particular columns

```
var xyz = from a in prod.Categories
                           where a.CatName.EndsWith("A")
                           select new { CatName=a.CatName, CatID=a.CatID, CatQty = a.CatQty};
```